# Creating FTP client for asp with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a little problem because on my website I can't really set permissions for the directories, it just doesn't work. I use filezilla and when I try to set them to some subdirectories of a default directory of the server that is publicly readable and writable it doesn't send me an error but when I want to save a file in one of that subdirectories from an asp page I get an error telling that I haven't got the permission to do so, I tried setting 777, so it should work. Using C# I created a FTP client that allows me to edit those subdirectories (those I couldn't edit from the asp page). My question is: can I create an asp page that uses a FTP client to access one of those subdirectories????? Thanks!!!

Comment: You may want to consider using a WCF web service instead of FTP. In case security matters on this one.

Comment: I highly recommend SecureBlackBox (http://www.eldos.com/sbb/) for FTP in .net

Comment: @Ulises: That sounds good. I've never tried wcf, could you explain what should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned before you could try WCF and stream files to your server using a web service.

WCF could be fairly complex; however, there is plenty of tutorials online.  You could start with this [simple tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hgvyas123/wcf-tutorial/) and adjust it to accomplish what you need. They even provide source code.

Basically what you need is a web service with one method, say:

```
void UploadFile(Stream object)
```

Then you need to create a web reference from your client (windows form app for example) by providing the address of your WCF web service. This will automatically create the classes you need to execute the method.

[This site has more info about streaming files:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)

Comment: How am I going to use this from an asp  page?

Comment: Are you using classic asp? The tag says asp.net, I was assuming you were using .net instead of classic asp. Anyway, if you decide to use asp.net check out the link to the tutorial, you need to create a new WCF project and deploy it just like you deploy a web app. Next, add a web reference in your project by providing the address of your WCV web service. This will automatically create the classes you need to execute the method.

Comment: Ok!!! I actually meant asp.net, but as I've started with this one I didn't knew there was normal asp. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

set permission to the  account that your website uses to access any directory.By default in IIS iis_user  account is used.Chage your web site user account to ftp user or any account that have the permission to access those directories.You can easily change this permission using iis7 manager.

Comment: Please note that this is a *terrible* security practice.

Comment: Anyway I'm not familiar with iis and I even don't know exactly what it is, but if it's possible, I think I don't have it, so it would be impossible for me to do as you say.